# How ETL script works?

Tags: aws-glue

Is that possible to write an ETL script using AWS Glue that executes the query in on-premise oracle database and the yielded result must be created as a table in AWS Glue data catalogue?

Answer (score 0):

No AWS is currently on-premise, including AWS Glue, which will extract data from the source and then transform/load on cloud. You need to use [AWS Outposts](https://aws.amazon.com/outposts/faqs/).

Comment: AWS Glue is capable of extracting data from on-premise database right?

Comment: Well, AWS Glue will not do it. You need to bring the data on the cloud, for example on some AWS database. What I meant is, you can automatize this transferring, for example with some lambda or using some software running on EDC or EDS, etc. Also, with Outposts, you will have machines on-premises and you can directly use your databases there.